# trying to understand the 'os's {npm packages} system memory analysis

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, npm, operating-system

I have a very simple code:

```
const os = require('os')
var num = os.freemem();
console.log('free mem is MB: ' + ((num) / 1024 / 1024));
```

Now, according to the documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_freemem), this returns a number, that supposedly represents the amount of free space in my system.

However, when I try to cross reference the result, I see no place that show the same amount of free space as the number 'os' package gives me.
I tried to find how 'os' does what it does, but I couldn't find the source code anywhere.

Can anyone explain to me how this works? what is the meaning of the number that 'os' returns? is it all hard disks? does it consider VM's? is it size or size on disk?
It's pretty annoying that there is no info about any of this...
thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: See https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?p=1&q=uv_get_free_memory&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @xmojmr: Thanks for the source code, but I'm not flount in c++ ... can you (or anyone else) explain what kind of data is returned? when I try to cross check the numbers with  windows disk maneger it gives me differen results...

Comment: On Windows OS the function returns [MEMORYSTATUSEX.ullAvailPhys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366770(v=vs.85).aspx) "_The amount of physical memory currently available, in bytes. This is the amount of physical memory that can be immediately reused without having to write its contents to disk first. It is the sum of the size of the standby, free, and zero lists_"